# Setting up journalctl on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, journalctl

I am trying to use journalctl on my remote Ubuntu Linux box. I understand that I need to setup a config file `journald.conf` under `/etc/systemd/` folder with permissions. But What I am struggling to understand how to enable the journalctl daemon in Linux in the first place. Is there any package that I need to install first?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @HunterSThompson     16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -L systemd | grep journalctl` and
`which journalctl`

Answer (score 5):

I think i got it working. I simply typed `sudo apt-get install systemd` to install `systemd` it informed :

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsystemd-journal0 systemd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
```

After this I get a `journald.conf` automatically created in `/etc/systemd/` folder. I guess this will work now - Thanks